# Possibility of displaying content based on logic using XAML for WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In an application which uses WPF (XAML) along with the MVVM pattern I have the following piece of XAML code which works just fine,

```
< DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status">
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>

      <Grid  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsCompleted, Converter={BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
               <Path Data=" "
                     Fill="# "
                     Stretch=" "
                     Height=""
                     Width=""/>
       </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The boolean property "IsCompleted" is defined in the corresponding view model which gets populated with "true" or "false". This functionality works as expected up until this point which is when the boolean property is true the expected icon is visible but the improvement I'm hoping to make is to introduce a logic where when the boolean property is set to false as it does right now, instead of having a blank space in the area (since the icon wont be visible) to display a string or text block instead, something like "In complete".

Is it possible to do this from the xaml side or should I make some changes in the view model?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `DataTrigger` to the `DataTemplate` that sets the `Visibility` property of the `Path` and/or a `TextBlock`, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Path x:Name="path"
                     Data=" "
                     Fill="# "
                     Stretch=" "
                     Height=""
                     Width="" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="InComplete" />
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="tb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```